# Use columns that are always NULL, never NULL, and sometimes NULL in the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, fedora, psycopg2

I'm using Python 3.6, PostgreSQL 9.6, and Psycopg2 2.6.2 on a Fedora 27 64-bit system.

I have a SELECT query called `my_query` that pulls data from about 15 columns in one table. Several of the columns *may* be NULL. It's written as

```
SELECT col_01, col_02, ... col_15  
FROM my_table  
WHERE (col_01, col_02, ... col_15) = (%s, %s, ... %s)
```

The data, called `my_data`, is written in a tuple as

```
(value_01, value_02, ... value_15)
```

When I run

```
cursor.execute(my_query, my_data)
cursor_result = cursor.fetchone()
```

`cursor_result` becomes `None`.

Assuming the problem was with the nullable columns, I removed them from my query and my data and `cursor_result` was no longer `None`.

I also tried a query with *only* nullable columns; it produced the same result as the original query: `cursor_result` became `None`.

My question: is there a way around my problem? I want to be able to SELECT columns that are never NULL, always NULL, or sometimes NULL.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Wow! That saved me *hours* (days, really) of very tedious work. If you put your comment in an answer I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI 99 standard for SQL introduced the `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` operator, which behaves identically to the equality comparisons involving non-null values but treats all `NULL`s as being the same (`NOT DISTINCT`, given the curious negative phrasing).

Most database products do not yet support this operator, so far as I'm aware, but luckily [PostgreSQL does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński - since it's unlikely that any variant that enumerates all of the possible options with `IS [NOT] NULL` tests and lots of `OR`s to combine them with equality tests would benefit from indexes either, I'm not sure it's worth mentioning as a downside. If the performance is acceptable and it does the job required, I'd certainly stop searching for alternatives at the point.